# Why I can't get the same json results when opening browser and using requests python?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to scrape the web https://jendela360.com/apartemen/jakarta-barat and found the api for supplying the json file https://api.jendela360.com/api/site/apartment-search?price=0&sort=popular&page=1&aptId=&radius=5&latitude=0&longitude=0&filter_type=area&area=jakarta-barat&rowsPerPage=100 . When I opened the api in browser I am able to see all the json results.

However when I tried my code:

```
header={
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'id-ID,id;q=0.9',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'cookie': '_ga=GA1.2.23833481.1667102529; _gid=GA1.2.3408225.1667102529; _fbp=fb.1.1667102531924.49727250',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="106", "Google Chrome";v="106", "Not;A=Brand";v="99"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    }


location='jakarta-barat'
resp = requests.get(f'https://api.jendela360.com/api/site/apartment-search?price=0&sort=popular&page=1&aptId=&radius=5&latitude=0&longitude=0&filter_type=area&area={location}&rowsPerPage=12',headers=header)
x=resp.json()['data']
print(x)
```

It returns data=[]

Please do help, the response is firing 200. However the data loaded is null.

Comment: If you're expecting a json response, you might want to put json in the `accept` header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as expected, no need to pass any extra header specially the **accept** and **accept-encoding**, as per your response you need to set headers `application/json`

```
import requests

location='jakarta-barat'
url = f"https://api.jendela360.com/api/site/apartment-search?price=0&sort=popular&page=1&aptId=&radius=5&latitude=0&longitude=0&filter_type=area&area={location}&rowsPerPage=100"

payload={}
headers = {}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
x=response.json()['data']
print(x)
```

Comment: I tried adding that, it doesn't change the result where the data returned is []. Guess it got something to do with the security features on the web